# A better performing way retrieving select attributes Collections of Large Objects in Java

Tags: java, performance, collections, guava

Is there a method where I can iterate a Collection and **only retrieve just a subset of attributes without loading/unloading the each of the full object to cache**? 'Cos it seems like a waste to load/unload the WHOLE (possibly big) object when I need only some attribute(s), especially if the objects are big. It might cause unnecessary cache conflicts when loading such unnecessary data, right?

When I meant to 'load to cache' I mean to 'process' that object via the processor. So there would be  objects of ex: 10 attributes. In the iterating loop I only use 1 of those. In such a scenario, I think its a waste to load all the other 9 attributes to the processor from the memory. Isn't there a solution to only extract the attributes without loading the full object?

Also, does something like Google's Guava solve the problem internally?

THANK YOU!

Comment: I don't understand - if they are in a `List` they are in memory already. If these are just files on the OS then you can read their attributes using the `File` object. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Give us some real example of what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was looking for just to improve my knowledge and this is not an actual problem. But a common problem nevertheless, I presume. I THINK I improved the question by removing any distractions regarding files etc. And i meant loading to **cache** not memory.. Sorry for the confusion and Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not usually the first place to look, but it's not certainly impossible that you're running into cache sharing problems. If you're really convinced (from realistic profiling or analysis of hardware counters) that this is a bottleneck worth addressing, you might consider altering your data structures to use parallel arrays of primitives (akin to column-based database storage in some DB architectures). e.g. one 'column' as a `float[]`, another as a `short[]`, a third as a `String[]`, all indexed by the same identifier. This structure allows you to 'query' individual columns without loading into cache any columns that aren't currently needed.

I have some low-level algorithmic code that would really benefit from C's `struct`. I ran some microbenchmarks on various alternatives and found that parallel arrays was the most effective option for my algorithms (that may or may not apply to your own).

Note that a parallel-array structure will be considerably more complex to maintain and mutate than using Objects in `java.util` collections. So I'll reiterate - I'd only take this approach after you've convinced yourself that the benefit will be worth the pain.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in Java to manage loading to processor caches, and there is no way to change how the JVM works with objects, so the answer is no. 
Java is not a low-level language and hides such details from the programmer.

The JVM will decide how much of the object it loads. It might load the whole object as some kind of read-ahead optimization, or load only the fields you actually access, or analyze the code during JIT compilation and do a combination of both.

Also, how large do you worry your objects are? I have rarely seen classes with more than a few fields, so I would not consider that big.

Comment: Like I said, this is not based on any current problem. I used to, however, iterate though 'Document' objects collection where a Document refers to a scraped website. Isn't this a real performance problem which adds up to quite a lot of tiny performance issues in very large systems? I'm surprised that there's no one else who addressed this problem

Comment: Also, this is not regarding 'managing' processor caches.. Its about 'being aware' of cache